# How to pass Javascript object to solidity contract?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I'm looking to store an entire Javascript object in an ERC-1155 fully on chain. It is a side-chain so storage expenses are not a problem.

What is the best way to go from an object in Javascript to a solidity contract then pack to Javascript?

Comment: @jabaa Javascript object, my bad

Comment: Can you serialize it and store the string?

Comment: @jabaa yep that works to get the data into the contract but ERC1155 mint requires data to be of type `bytes`